# Srednicki's book chapter 8

Tags: quantum-field-theory, regularization, wick-rotation

Reading first page in chapter 8 of Srednicki's it reads:

> To employ the $\epsilon$ trick, we multiply $H_0$ with $1-i\epsilon$. The results are equivalent to replacing $m^2$ with $m^2-i\epsilon$.

Now, our Hamiltonian is

$H_0=\frac{1}{2}\Pi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2$

so making the replacement he suggests ($m^2\to{}m^2-i\epsilon$) we would have

$H_0(1-i\epsilon)=\frac{1}{2}\Pi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{i\epsilon}{2}\phi^2$

while on the other hand, in reality

$H_0(1-i\epsilon)=\frac{1}{2}\Pi^2+\frac{1}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2+\frac{1}{2}m^2\phi^2-\frac{i\epsilon}{2}\Pi^2-\frac{i\epsilon}{2}(\nabla\phi)^2-\frac{i\epsilon}{2}m^2\phi^2$

And we see that both terms don't agree. How can both expressions be equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

Some terms in $H_0$ can be absorbed into the definition of $\epsilon$.

To understand the validity of this substitution, you must go back to chapter 7 and calculate according to eqn. (7.2)-(7.6).

You will find "we can absorb the positive coefficient into $\epsilon$ to get..."

Comment: But the substitutions in (7.2)–(7.6) are different. That hamiltonian has an m in both terms, whereas the one in this chapter has an m in only one term.